# Could not autowire field: com.srk.dao.UserDao com.srk.service.UserServiceImpl.userDao; org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Im am creating spring security with role based authentication project demo but getting issue like

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.srk.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/sdnext-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder

my Helloworldcontroller.java is

```
package com.srk.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.srk.service.UserService;
import com.srk.service.UserServiceImpl;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {
//  protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/home" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String homePage(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hi, Welcome to mysite");
        return "welcome";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String adminPage(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", getPrincipal());
        return "admin";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/db", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String dbaPage(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", getPrincipal());
        return "dba";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/Access_Denied", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String accessDeniedPage(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", getPrincipal());
        return "accessDenied";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage() {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logoutPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null) {
            new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
        }
        return "redirect:/login?logout";
    }

    private String getPrincipal() {
        String userName = null;
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            userName = ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
        } else {
            userName = principal.toString();
        }
        return userName;
    }

}
```

AbstractDao.java is

```
package com.srk.dao;

import java.io.Serializable;

import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public abstract class AbstractDao<PK extends Serializable, T> {

    private final Class<T> persistentClass;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public AbstractDao(){
        this.persistentClass =(Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[1];
    }

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getSession(){
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T getByKey(PK key) {
        return (T) getSession().get(persistentClass, key);
    }

    public void persist(T entity) {
        getSession().persist(entity);
    }

    public void delete(T entity) {
        getSession().delete(entity);
    }

    protected Criteria createEntityCriteria(){
        return getSession().createCriteria(persistentClass);
    }

}
```

UserDaoImpl.java is

```
package com.srk.dao;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.srk.model.User;

@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<Integer, User> implements UserDao {
    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public User findById(int id) {
        return getByKey(id);
    }

    public User findBySSO(String sso) {
        Criteria crit = createEntityCriteria();
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("ssoId", sso));
        return (User) crit.uniqueResult();
    }

}
```

UserServiceImple.java is

```
package com.srk.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.srk.dao.UserDao;
import com.srk.dao.UserDaoImpl;
import com.srk.model.User;

@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    public User findById(int id) {
        return userDao.findById(id);
    }

    public User findBySso(String sso) {
        return userDao.findBySSO(sso);
    }

}
```

sdnext-servlet.xml is

```
<beans xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.srk.*" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />


    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        id="jspViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springsecurity" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        id="sessionFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.srk.model.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <!-- <property name="hibernateProperties"> <props> <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop> 
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop> <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto} 
            </prop> </props> </property> -->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
        id="hibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />

    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/home" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin**"
            access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/dba**"
            access="hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/login"
            username-parameter="ssoId" password-parameter="password"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="customSuccessHandler"
            authentication-failure-url="/Access_Denied" />
        <security:csrf />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider
            user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService" />
    </security:authentication-manager>
    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="com.srk.service.CustomUserDetailsService" />
    <bean id="customSuccessHandler" class="com.srk.configuration.CustomSuccessHandler" />

    <bean id="userDao" class="com.srk.dao.UserDaoImpl" />
    <bean id="userService" class="com.srk.service.UserServiceImpl" />

</beans>
```

And My jars are

```
antlr-2.7.7
aopalliance-1.0
commons-logging-1.2
dom4j-1.6.1
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final
hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final
jandex-1.1.0.Final
javassist-3.18.1-GA
javax.servlet.jsp-api-2.3.1
javax.servlet-api-3.1.0
jstl-1.2
jta-1.1
mysql-connector-java-5.1.31
spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE
spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE
spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE
spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE
spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE
spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE
spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE
spring-security-config-4.0.1.RELEASE
spring-security-core-4.0.1.RELEASE
spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE
spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE
spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE
spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE
xml-apis-1.0.b2
```

Please help me....i stuck in code .....Thanks in advance

Error is:

```
  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.srk.dao.UserDaoImpl com.srk.service.UserServiceImpl.userDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.srk.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/sdnext-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.srk.dao.UserDaoImpl com.srk.service.UserServiceImpl.userDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.srk.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/sdnext-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 49 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.srk.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/sdnext-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
        at      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
        ... 51 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.srk.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/sdnext-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 62 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/sdnext-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
        ... 64 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:343)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
        ... 74 more

   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.srk.service.UserServiceImpl com.srk.controller.HelloWorldController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.srk.dao.UserDaoImpl com.srk.service.UserServiceImpl.userDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.srk.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/sdnext-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 36 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.srk.dao.UserDaoImpl com.srk.service.UserServiceImpl.userDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.srk.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/sdnext-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
        ... 38 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.srk.dao.UserDaoImpl com.srk.service.UserServiceImpl.userDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.srk.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/sdnext-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 49 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.srk.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/sdnext-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
        ... 51 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.srk.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/sdnext-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder
        at 
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/sdnext-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder
```

Comment: For starters add the full stacktrace instead of a snippet

Answer (score 1):

try, changing to

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        id="sessionFactory">
        <constructor ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.srk.model.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <!-- <property name="hibernateProperties"> <props> <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop> 
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop> <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto} 
            </prop> </props> </property> -->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.html

Comment: I have added the error snippet above...please help mi to solve the error